# Audio to Spectrogram Image

Tags: python, image, audio, spectrogram

I expect I can convert an audio file or waveform to the spectrogram image where:

1. X-axis represent time (horizontal axis), where goes to the right meaning to the ending duration of audio.
2. Y-axis represent frequency (vertical axis), where goes to the up meaning to the maximum of frequency from audio that. So the range is `(20hz until the max possible audio frequency can reach)`. I also expect I can set scale in this axis such as linearly or logarithm or with my custom function like: `f(p) = 2p` where `p is n-th pixel from 0 to the maximum heigh of image` and `f(p)` is frequency.
3. Black pixel represent no amplitude
4. White pixel represent the max possible audio amplitudo can reach
5. That's mean, gray pixel represent amplitude value that between of them
6. I also expect I able to specify resolution of image such as `720*480`

So is there python library/package that can I install, or I should calculate manually which I should transform from time domain waveform to the frequency domain waveform using Fast Fourier Transform?

Comment: [Here](https://dropsofai.com/understanding-audio-data-fourier-transform-fft-and-spectrogram-features-for-a-speech-recognition-system/) you can find different kind of plotting of audio file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check librosa library, should conain all that you need. For instance https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html